Styling Material-UI "DateCalendar" component using Tailwind CSS
I am working on implementing a mini-calendar very similar to Google's calendar that appears on top-left corner (there are some design changes). I am using Tailwind for styling react-components and have chosen to use Material-UI DateCalendar I found it to be the correct choice as there are minor differences from my design and I want to add Tailwind classes to this component how can I achieve this.
My calendar design-

I already have Tailwind setup for my project, I understand using Tailwind classes could be conflicting with material-ui - Using material ui and Tailwind css in react projects, but I would need this one component only (I guess).
Building it from scratch could be more time consuming but I am open to use some other components library as well also will work on building it from scratch if not possible.
Most relative question I could find was this - MUI Date Calendar styling, but I need to achieve this using Tailwind.
I welcome your suggestions and answers, thank you.

Not sure on achieving this using Tailwind.
If you are using Mui DatePicker you can achieve the design you shared using the below code using Mui styling. I assume you are familiar with Use Mui with Tailwind.
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
  <StaticDatePicker
    defaultValue={dayjs('2023-12-06')}
    className={""}
    slotProps={{toolbar: {hidden: true}, actionBar: {actions: []}}}
    showDaysOutsideCurrentMonth
    sx={{
      button: {
        "&.Mui-selected": {
          backgroundColor: "black"
        },
      },
      "& .MuiPickersCalendarHeader-labelContainer": {
        mr: "0",
        svg: {
          display: "none"
        },
      }
    }}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>

The output I achieved is


Thanks bro for putting time & effort accept my upvote but still there are some modifications I will need to make.
